# How to get macosx Log-in User Name in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

please let me know how to get the currently logged in user's name or mac machine name (if possible) in objective-c. Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's [NSUserName()](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSUserName)

Comment: I think everyone should give David a point for such a thorough and obviously well researched answer.

Comment: And don't forget [**NSFullUserName()**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSFullUserName) :-)

Answer (score 7):

C function:  getpwuid() which return the struct passwd:

```
       struct passwd {
           char   *pw_name;       /* username */
           char   *pw_passwd;     /* user password */
           uid_t   pw_uid;        /* user ID */
           gid_t   pw_gid;        /* group ID */
           char   *pw_gecos;      /* user information */
           char   *pw_dir;        /* home directory */
           char   *pw_shell;      /* shell program */
       };
```

----------------------Code----------------

```
#include <pwd.h>
register uid_t uid;
struct passwd *uid_pw;
uid = geteuid ();
uid_pw = getpwuid (uid);
strcpy(uname,uid_pw->pw_name)
```

//similarly other information

Comment: What's the point if there's higher level functions in the frameworks - that are guaranteed to give you the correct, OS X level answer and not some potentially random rubbish answer of the underlying UNIX system..?!

Comment: I just mean that there is method for lower level language, so if someone don't want to use objective c function then they can go for it. Yeah, both are same and both guarantee the correct result.

Comment: @Jay When would getpwuid() return garbage? It just calls OpenDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSUserName()`. This will return the name of the current logged in user.

```
NSString *userName = NSUserName();
```