# How to get MacOS username in .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, pinvoke

I have a (C#) console application in .NET Core on MacOS.

**How do I get the current username?**

I tried

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER");

and

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");

but I get nothing back.

I would like to try P/Invoke against `getpwuid()` based on the hint described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18842029/4658148

but I'm not sure what the syntax should be from C# for that `passwd` struct.

Any help appreciated on this, as well as any pointers to resources on P/Invoke that can help me learn the ropes of P/Invoke from .NET Core into MacOS native code.

Comment: Does `Environment.UserName` exist and work?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow when I get to work. I can't believe I missed that one xD. Must've been too focused on pinvoke. This sounds like it should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("UserName: {0}", Environment.UserName);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I got so focused on looking a P/Invoke solution that I didn't notice that xD. Funny thing is - the .NET Core documentation on the `Environment.UserName` property is that on Unix systems it wraps a call to `getpwuid_r()` , so I was kinda on the right track, just late xD.